# Pass data using the internal storage in an android application

Tags: java, android

I tried to implement [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to write and read data from internal storage, but when I'm trying to read written data from the same Android application it does not give me any result. What can be the error?? Following is the code I have used.

```
public class SecondScreen extends Activity {

  String FILENAME = "hello_file";
  String string = "hello world!";



  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);

  //Using the Internal Storage
    try{
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();

    }

    catch(Exception e){

    }


     TextView result;
     result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);

 try{

     String test = "";
     FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("hello_file");
     fis.read(test.getBytes());
     fis.close();
     result.setText(test);

    }

    catch(Exception e){

    }


}
```

manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wrd.ws"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ReadWriteDataActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

The updated code :

```
public class ReadWriteDataActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
String line;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    writeFileToInternalStorage();
    readFileFromInternalStorage();
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

//        tv.setText(line);

```
}
private void writeFileToInternalStorage() 
{
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try 
    {

         File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
         myFile.createNewFile();



      writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myFile.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)));
      writer.write("This is a test1."+ eol);
      writer.write("This is a test2." + eol);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
      if (writer != null) 
      {
        try 
        {
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}



private void readFileFromInternalStorage() 
{
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try 
    {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("myFile.txt")));
        //String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            buffer.append(line + eol);
        }
         tv.setText(buffer.toString().trim());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (input != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                input.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you put exception by printing exception?

Comment: No any exception messages. It runs normally, but doesn't show the written string ("hello world!") to the file.

Comment: write() method is going to write in byte format, so you can't read it with normal text viewer like notepad @Grant

Comment: can you put your app's manifest file code here.you need to add `read/write permission to external storage` into your application's manifest file

Comment: @Grant thats the problem what Lucifer suggest, I agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedReader` class while dealing with Flie API. have a look at following methods,

**Writing in File**

```
private void writeFileToInternalStorage() 
{
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try 
    {
      writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myfile", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)));
      writer.write("This is a test1." + eol);
      writer.write("This is a test2." + eol);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
      if (writer != null) 
      {
        try 
        {
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Reading File**

```
private void readFileFromInternalStorage() 
{
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try 
    {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("myfile")));
        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            buffer.append(line + eol);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (input != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                input.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add read/write permission to external storage into my application's manifest file ??

Comment: I can't get the result from your code. What would be the cause?

Comment: ok Mafifest file looks ok, can you please upload your updated code too, with error if any.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Lucifer for spending your time to solve my problem.. It worked successfully.....

Comment: yes, then you need to set file mode `MODE_WORLD_READABLE | MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE - Read / Write access`

Comment: Then what are the changes need to do for this line    
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("/sdcard/mytext.txt")));

Comment: sorry, actually no need to do change, this file can be easily read/write by any other application too

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have problem in the below code:

```
String test = "";
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("hello_file");
fis.read(test.getBytes());
```

You are passing `test.getBytes()` and `test` is of in-sufficient size. So the fix is to read bytes in an array.

```
byte[] allBytes = new byte[100];
int indexInAllBytes = 0;
int bytesRead = 0;
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("hello_file");

while(bytesRead != -1) {
  bytesRead = fis.read(allBytes, indexInAllBytes, allBytes.length);

  indexInAllBytes+=bytesRead;

  if(indexInAllBytes >= allBytes.length) {
     // We are exceeding the buffer size. Need bigger bytes array
     break;
  }
  // Also you can convert into string using StringBuilder.
}
```

NOTE: BufferedReader(s) are good for reading/writing text files. If you want binary files then you can use the above logic with slight improvements.